# how to use custom UIBarButtonItem in interface whice all use custom UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

how to use custom UIBarButtonItem in interface whice all use custom UINavigationBar

Not written again in every interface.

Is there a unified method to uniform setting?

```
UIImage image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
UIButton button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:highLightImagePath] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

A lot of interface backBarButtonItem need custom，code is the same，I don't want to write N times

Comment: you want the entire program to have this custom button n custom navigation bar?

Comment: @darkmystel lot of interface backBarButtonItem need custom，code is the same，I don't want to write N times

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in a singleton global-variables file, like

GlobalVariable.h

```
+(UIBarButtonItem*)customButton;
```

GlobalVariable.m

```
+(UIBarButtonItem*)customButton{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:highLightImagePath] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem* btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    return btn;
}
```

Then, import `GlobalVariable.h` in the views you want the button to appear and call

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [GlobalVariable customButton];
```

You can keep GlobalVariable there, in case you need other variables too.

Comment: I think the method should be a (+) class method and not an (-) instance method